# scipy.curve_fit ValueError: Unable to determine number of fit parameters

Tags: scipy, curve-fitting, valueerror, scipy-optimize, data-fitting

I'm new to python and I'm trying to do a curve fit on my data, this is the script

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# define the function you want to fit
def my_func(x):
    return x**3 + np.log10(x) + 2
    
print('f(1)=',my_func(1))

# load data from file
x_data,y_data,=np.loadtxt('dati1.dat', unpack=True, usecols=(0,2))

x_data = np.array(x_data)
y_data = np.array(y_data)
print(x_data,y_data)

# perform the curve fit
popt,pcov=curve_fit(my_func,x_data,y_data)

# plot the results
plt.plot(x_data, y_data, 'o', label='data')
plt.plot(x_data, my_func(x_data, *popt), '-', label='fit')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

but it gives me back this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "grafico2.py", line 20, in <module>
    popt,pcov=curve_fit(my_func,x_data,y_data)
  File "/Users/myprofile/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_minpack_py.py", line 779, in curve_fit
    raise ValueError("Unable to determine number of fit parameters.")
ValueError: Unable to determine number of fit parameters.
```

I've printed both a random value of the function and the x (x_data) and y (y_data) I'm giving as an input so I know they work. I can't figure out the error

Comment: Well, at the moment there are zero fit parameters in `my_func()`. what is supposed to be fitted?

Comment: For instance, try changing `my_func()` to `def my_func(x, a, b): return a*x**3 + b*np.log10(x) + 2`. You'll have two parameters instead of 0.