# Curve fitting error: unable to determine number of fit parameters

Tags: matplotlib, scipy

I wanted to create a curve fit for specific data.[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEdIz.png). for that I intended to use the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as sp

Mcore, Nbs = np.genfromtxt("star.txt", unpack=True, skip_header=1)

Mcore2 = [0.001*item for item in Mcore]

sigma = np.sqrt(Nbs)

plt.errorbar(Mcore2, Nbs, sigma, fmt=".")
plt.yscale("log")
plt.xscale("log")

def chi(a):
    return 0.39*np.log(a)+1.22

sp.optimize.curve_fit(chi, Mcore2, Nbs)
```

However, when i run the code the following problem appears ValueError: Unable to determine number of fit parameters. What can i do to solve this?

Comment: You have the same problem as this other SO posted a few hours earlier: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75897039/scipy-curve-fit-valueerror-unable-to-determine-number-of-fit-parameters

Comment: Please look at the documentation before posting questions, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html#scipy.optimize.curve_fit. There are examples at the bottom of that documentation page.